FastAPI StreamingResponse start download while waiting for data
I want to send a file to a user, however the file is generated asynchronously via a thread which can take a long time (even 30 seconds).
I would like the browser to show the file being downloaded right away (with 0 bytes and unknown size), tried via cUrl and it works but with a browser (Chrome or Firefox) this doesn't happen, the download only starts after the first bytes have been sent.
The only way I've been able to find is to send empty characters (\u200B) while waiting for the file to be generated (as suggested in this similar problem Chrome doesn't show file as being downloaded until 8 bytes are sent (Firefox does)), but this way the resulting file contains these characters at the beginning, which then gives problems when loading on other systems.
This is an example of the code (simulating asynchronous creation of the file)
async def async_read_file():
    # this code simulate the activate waiting for the file to be created
    count = 0
    while count < 5:
        await asyncio.sleep(2)
        count += 1

    file = open('file.zip', 'rb')
    while True:
        data = file.read(64 * 1024)
        if not data:
            break
        yield data


@app.get('/download')
async def download():
    async def iterate_file_():
        async for chunk in async_read_file():
            yield chunk

    response = StreamingResponse(iterate_file_(), headers={
        "Content-Disposition": "attachment; filename*=utf-8''{}".format(quote('file.zip'))})

    return response

I'm using FastAPI version 0.109.2.

Does this answer your question? You might find this answer helpful as well.

I would suggest following the approach described in the linked answers above, when you have to return files/data that would be ready to download at a later stage.

Thanks Chris, but this doesn't seem to be the answer.
The problem is that this is an interaction from a Browser, so it should start downloading immediately (otherwise the user thinks it doesn't work) and can't be changed to a 201 response and then a get when ready (we already do this in other endpoints, but this is not the case)

You could have the user click on a "Create file"/"Generate data" button, and display a loading bar until the file/data is ready to be downloaded. Once the data is ready for downloading, you could then present the user with the "Download" button to click on and download the data. Please have a closer look at the approach explained in the linked answers above.

what do you send? Some files have magic number at the beginning which never changes - so you could send this value and later send file without this value. For example zip always starts with chars PK. See more List of file signatures - Wikipedia

The file could be a JSON, a CSV, a XSLX or a zip

I would like to leave it as a last resort to change the download behavior and make it in busy waiting, because this involves changing the frontend, backend, tests, etc.
